# Mass Mail partially works

Tags: emails

Mass Mail works fine when I send to all Super Users (3), but NOT when I send to all Registered users (64?). Even when the other setting are the same (BCC on, HTML off, etc...). I'm using Joomla 3.4.8, on SiteGround web hosting.

I've tried both phpmail and sendmail. Both have the same results, just a different error msg:

**phpmail:**

> **Notice** 
>   Could not instantiate mail function

**sendmail:**

> **Notice** 
>   Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Comment: The issue was my hosting company limits the number of recipients per message to 40 (up to 400 per hours on on basic hosting package). Over that and the send fails. 

I build myself a modified version of the Mass Mail component to sent one message at a time. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to tell you mate, but Joomla's built-in Mass Mail is a joke of extension! 
In my nine years of using Joomla I have never been able to use it for anything usefull, and I always felt angry for not being able to disable it as a core extension.

I would seriously recommend to you to use decent newsletter extension such as heavy-weight champion [AcyMailing](https://www.acyba.com/acymailing/features.html), which is even in it's smallest and free Starter Edition, very powerful and reliable.